# After inserting, only one character is inserted of "string" in database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Below is my table screenshot:
[image: Main table design]

Data after insertion
[image: Data after insertion]

Code in C#

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionsession.Con);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("finalinsert", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = flightsession.Sflightid;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fcid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = flightsession.Sflightcostid;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ftid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = flightsession.Sflighttimingid;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@frdn", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ford", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = flightsession.Regdate;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = loginsession.Auser;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@paid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = "1";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@source", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = flightsession.Sscource;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@destination", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = flightsession.Sdestination;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fn", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = flightsession.Sflightname;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fc", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = flightsession.Total;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fty", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = flightsession.Stype;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fcl", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = flightsession.Sflightclass;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ft", SqlDbType.Time)).Value =flightsession.Sflighttime;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Succesful");
con.Close();
flightreceipt ob18 = new flightreceipt();
ob18.ShowDialog();
this.Hide();
```

Code for creating procedure in SQL server 2008

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[finalinsert] @fid int,@fcid int,@ftid int,@frdn date,@ford date,@uid int,
@paid int,@source varchar,@destination varchar,@fc varchar,@fty varchar,@fcl varchar,@ft time(7) ,@fn varchar
AS
INSERT INTO [shangrila].[dbo].[flight_reg_table]
           ([flight_id]
           ,[flight_cost_id]
           ,[flight_time_id]
           ,[flight_reg_date_now]
           ,[flight_on_reg_date]
           ,[user_id]
           ,[paid]
           ,[source]
           ,[destination]
           ,[flight_name]
           ,[flight_cost]
           ,[flight_type]
           ,[flight_class]
           ,[flight_time])
     VALUES
           (@fid,
           @fcid,
           @ftid,
           @frdn,
           @ford,
           @uid,
           @paid,
           @source,
           @destination,
           @fn,
           @fc,
           @fty,
           @fcl,
           @ft)
```

I tried to figure out why! But i am stuck.
Remember all format which I am inserting is string.
Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your sproc your VARCHAR needs to have a length associated with it, such as `VARCHAR(50)`. The default length is 1, so SQL is only sending one character to your sproc.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[finalinsert]
     @fid int
    ,@fcid int
    ,@ftid int
    ,@frdn date 
    ,@ford date
    ,@uid int
    ,@paid int
    ,@source varchar(50)
    ,@destination varchar(50)
    ,@fc varchar(50)
    ,@fty varchar(50)
    ,@fcl varchar(50)
    ,@ft time(7)
    ,@fn varchar(50)
AS
```

You may also need to change the datatype in your call as well to include the length, but ADO.NET *might* handle it correctly.

Comment: -Thanks alot :) I think that the problem will be resolve but after modifying new error is coming  cant convert string to datetime format :(

Comment: You can probably just use `DateTime.Now` instead of turning it into a string. But that's my guess since I don't know which DateTime is causing a problem.

Answer (score 3):

**The root cause is mentioned by @Talljoe, as well as by @Jethro.**

Anyway, your C# code will be rather better if will look like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = commandName;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    ...
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@source", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = flightsession.Sscource;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@destination", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = flightsession.Sdestination;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = flightsession.Sflightname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = flightsession.Total;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fty", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = flightsession.Stype;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fcl", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = flightsession.Sflightclass;

    connection.Open(); // open just now!
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
} // using block call Dispose() for each object locker to guarantee close of the connection
```

Read more about [SqlConnection.Dispose()](http://www.google.com/search?q=sqlconnection.dispose%20site%3amsdn.microsoft.com) and [using(){} block](http://www.google.com/search?q=using%20block).

Comment: @abatishchev:-New errors comes now can't convert string to date time .The format in my database of time(7) is 09:00:00.0000000 and my string is 09:00:00

Comment: @pixelerator: In which column?

Comment: @abatishchev:-I figured it out First convert it into datetime using datetime.parse method  DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(flightsession.Sflighttime);  and then  again convert it into string dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); and thanks for suggesting the using and dispose method :)

Comment: @pixelerator: Have you tried `SqlDbType.DateTime` without `ToString()`?

Comment: @abatishchev :- i didn't try ,i will try :)

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure varchar needs to change to show the length of the field. Ie @fn varchar(50).

Answer (score 0):

Along with the data type of the variables, you should mention the size of the data item. Ex: varchar(50)