# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am running into an run time error issue that I may understand what the run time error is saying but I do not why it is happening.

I have a `List<MetaData>` called `metaDatas` that I would like to save to a Table called `MetaDataTable` in SQL Server 2014.

The `MetaData` class is defined below

```cs
public class MetaData
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnType { get; set; }
    public int ColumnSize { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}
```

The `MetaDataTable` in my SQL Server is defined below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MetaDataTable](
    [ColumnName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ColumnType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ColumnSize] [int] NULL,
    [TableName] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My script to save `List<MetaData>` in to SQL Server is below (I have stripped out the irrelevant code):

```cs
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    string databaseTable = "MetaDataTable";
    string SQLstr = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} (ColumnName, ColumnType,ColumnSize,TableName)" +
" VALUES ('@ColumnName', '@ColumnType', '@ColumnSize', '@TableName')", databaseTable);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnType", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnSize", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    foreach (MetaData metaData in metaDatas)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value = metaData.ColumnName;
        cmd.Parameters["@ColumnType"].Value = metaData.ColumnType;
        cmd.Parameters["@ColumnSize"].Value = metaData.ColumnSize;
        cmd.Parameters["@TableName"].Value = metaData.TableName;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

When `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is executed, I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@ColumnSize' to data type int.

The `@ColumnSize` is clearly defined as type int and its data is also of value `int`

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: `Why is this happening?` - because you are passing the literal string `'@ColumnSize'`, not a variable `@ColumnSize`.

Comment: I suspect that your next question will be why only the [first letters of the variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5613467/11683) get inserted.

Comment: Aggrr... Should have used @ColumnSize... rookie mistake!! Thanks GSerg!!